# copy first input field into the following input fields using jquery

Tags: jquery, forms, input, duplicates, clone

The form

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
  name_field
  <input type="text" name="field_1" id="field_1" />
  <a href="#" id="dup" name="dup" >Use same</a>
  <input type="text" name="field_2" id="field_2" />
  <input type="text" name="field_3" id="field_3" />
  ...
  <input type="text" name="field_x" id="field_x" />
</form>
```

I am looking for an ajax script the will clone field_1 into field_1 till field_x..
This is a way of populating the name of the team on all players.

```
  $(".dup").click(function() {
    var myinput =  $( ".field_1" ).val();
    $("input[class^='field_']").html(myinput);
  });

$(".dup").live("click", function(e) {
    var count = $(".form1 fieldset").length + 1;
    $(this).parent().clone().insertBefore("#sbmt").find("input[type=text]").attr({
        "id": "input" + count,
        "name": "input" + count
    }).val("");
});
```

// Update:

It turned out that may field is this type: 
    
And changes are done in multiples of 3.. so

```
<input id="field_1" type="text" name="Item[fields][1]" ><a href="#" id="dup1">Use Info</a>
<input id="field_2" type="text" name="Item[fields][2]" ><a href="#" id="dup2">Use Team</a>
<input id="field_3" type="text" name="Item[fields][3]" ><a href="#" id="dup3">Use Year</a>
<input id="field_4" type="text" name="Item[fields][4]" >
<input id="field_5" type="text" name="Item[fields][5]" >
<input id="field_6" type="text" name="Item[fields][6]" >
<input id="field_7" type="text" name="Item[fields][7]" >
<input id="field_8" type="text" name="Item[fields][8]" >
<input id="field_9" type="text" name="Item[fields][9]" >
....
<input id="field_2" type="text" name="Item[fields][x]" >


so clicking 
dup1, clone field[1] into [4],[7] ...[1+3(i)]  
dup2, clone field[2] into [5],[8],...[2+3(i)] 
dup3, clone field[3] into [6],[9],...[3+3(i)]
```

i cannot use id value since it is inconsistent.. It has values such as year_league66134

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.val()` , You didn't define `class` and used it instead of class use id attribute to solve your issues.

**Repalce `class`**

```
 $(".field_1").val();
 $("input[class^='field_']").html(myinput);
```

**with `ID`**

```
 $("#field_1").val();
 $("input[id^='field_']").val(myinput);
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use .val to set the value also

```
  $(".dup").click(function() {
    var myinput =  $( ".field_1" ).val();
    $("input[name^='field_']").val(myinput);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

[.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

change

```
 $("input[class^='field_']").html(myinput);
```

to

```
 $("input[class^='field_']").val(myinput);
```

Comment: Anything like this?
     `for($i=1; i<(Item[fields].length+1)/3; $i++) {
     $("input[name^='fields][1+3(i)").val(myinput);
     }`

Answer (score 0):

Try this function

```
function CreateInputText(index) {
        var input = document.createElement('input');
        input.setAttribute('type', 'text');
        input.setAttribute('id', 'field_' + index);
        input.setAttribute('name', 'field_' + index);
        $(input).insertBefore('#sbmt');
    }
```

And you can call it on document ready if you need like

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            CreateInputText(i);
        }
    });
```

Comment: The problem with this answer is that the input field is not limited to 5.. It changes according to how many T-shirt a customer is ordering

Comment: use a variable and use as many times as the customer is ordering ;)

Comment: I am actually looking to use the lenght of input array: for ($i=1; i < (Item[fields].length+1)/3; $i++)